# expression must be a modifiable lvalue C/C++(137)

Tags: arrays, c, struct, lvalue

I am trying to assign an 2D array to another 2D array that is defined in a struct. But I get this error; 'expression must be a modifiable lvalue C/C++(137)'.

Here is the code;

```
#define NUM_TEMPLATES 4

float templateForehand1[3][50];
struct templ_st {
    float frame[3][50];
};
struct templ_st templates[NUM_TEMPLATES];

templates[0].frame = templateForehand1;
```

I am getting the error for the last line.

Any insight for why this error happens will be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you think that every (static) array is a pointer, and you can just assign one pointer to another. That simply doesn't work here. Perhaps if you really use the address of `.frame` and `tempalteForehand1`, but is that indeed what you want? Why not copy the values in a (double) loop?

Comment: You can't assign an entire array in one assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assign arrays in C language.

You need to copy it or use pointer.

```
    memcpy(templates[0].frame, templateForehand1, sizeof(templates[0].frame));
```

or

```
struct templ_st {
    float (*frame)[50];
};

/* ... */

templates[0].frame = templateForehand1;
```

But the 2nd option will not provide a deep copy of the array only reference to it.

Another option is to use structs as both objects

```
struct templ_st {
    float frame[3][50];
};

struct templ_st templateForehand1 ={{ /* init */ }};

/*   ... */
    struct templ_st templates[NUM_TEMPLATES];

    templates[0].frame = templateForehand1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a struct containing an array to another struct of the same type. However, C doesn't allow assignment/initialization of raw arrays - it's just how the language was designed.

Option 1 - use structs only:

```
struct templ_st {
    float frame[3][50];
};

const struct templ_st template1 = { .frame = {/* array init list here */} };
struct templ_st templates[NUM_TEMPLATES];
...
templates[0] = template1;
```

Option 2 - `memcpy`:

```
memcpy(templates[0].frame, templateForehand1, sizeof(templates[0].frame));
```